# How to make MSSQL connection using Node.js in vue.js frontend?

Tags: javascript, json, sql-server, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to connect Vue.js app to the remote MSSQL server.

I am using node.js, [mssql library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql).

After setting up I get error.

How to make configuration settings in order to connect to mssql?
How to solve issues related to installation of libraries?

```
    ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors                                                        1:39:06 PM

    These dependencies were not found:

    * dgram in ./node_modules/native-dns-cache/lookup.js, ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/server.js and 2 others
    * fs in ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/platform.js

    To install them, you can run: npm install --save dgram fs
```

**package.json** dependencies:

```
  ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dgram": "^1.0.1",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "firebase": "^4.10.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "highcharts": "^6.0.7",
    "mssql": "^4.1.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.3",
    "vue-highcharts": "0.0.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^0.17.7",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  }, ...
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong ... `vue.js` is a client side framework?

Comment: yes , https://vuejs.org

Comment: and mssql is a server side npm module, has no way of using in a "browser" in other words ... if so, that's your problem - you'll also have the issue with `dgram` ... as that is nodejs builtin, and browsers don't run nodejs ... you'll need to implement the database "stuff" on your server, and use plain ol' AJAX or REST or whatever you decide to communicate between client and your server

Comment: @JaromandaX  Thank you but where I have to initialize the code.


An example where import `import sql from 'mssql' ` in my "main.js" app and where Server Config file have to be.
[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connect-callback)

Comment: probably, I don't know, you started by trying to make client code using server only packages, so, not sure what you need to do on your server

Comment: @JaromandaX Trying to make simple server connection


`const sql = require('mssql')
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection

  var config = {
    userName: 'USERNAME',
    password: 'PASSWORD',
    server: 'IP Address',
    // For Microsoft Azure:
    options: {
      encrypt: true,
      database: 'DATABASE_NAME'
    }
  }
  var connection = new Connection(config);
  connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    // If no error, then good to proceed.
    console.log("Connected")
  }) `

Comment: good, sounds like you've figured it ouw

Comment: Not quite there, 

When I request  mssql `const sql = require('mssql')` then  error and ask me to install  `dgram fs`.

Comment: well, require them (this is still server side, right, you're not still trying to compile for client side code, are you?)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. As I am very new in this environment. Vue app renders client-side. I build server-side using template "[webpack-ssr](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/webpack-ssr)".
Here is more information about [server-side rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html)

here is my test code:

```
...

const sql = require('mssql')

...

// Create connection to database
const databaseConfig = {
  userName: 'USER_NAME',
  password: 'PASSWORD',
  server: 'SERVER_NAMECLOUDAPP.AZURE.COM',
  database: 'DATABASE',
  options: {
       encrypt: true // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
   }
}

...
```

Data conncetion:

```
// mssql connect for database 

sql.connect(databaseConfig, err => {

    // ... error checks

if (err) {
  console.log('error: ' + err)

} else {
  console.log('conencted')
}
// Query

new sql.Request().query('select 1 as number', (err , result) => {
    // ... error checks

       ...

    console.dir(result + ' hmmm ... not good')
})
})

...
```